# Regular expression to count characters after coma

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I build a regular expression that will replace each comma with a '.' decimal point if there are more than 3 or less than 3 digits.

that is 4,444 is correct and stay like that but 3,33 will be 3.33 or 4,4444 will be 4.444

similarly it can be like this as well 1,234,45,6789, and it should become 1,234.45.6789

Comment: show your current efforts

Comment: I cannot figure it out the regex :) 
number = number.replace(/,/g, '.') 
This is all I have to replace , with a . i dont know how the counting works in regex

Comment: please move that effort to the question (don't post it as a comment)

Comment: In the case of `11,333,22,333` would you like it to be formatted as `11,333.22,333` or `11,333.22.333`?

Comment: 11,33.22,333
basically we have thousand separators in numbers that is, a comma after after 3 digits. for all the wrongly placed separators i want to convert them into dots (or any orher symbol)

Comment: I've edited my answer, you should have more luck with my second regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function commaToDot(number) {
  let regex = /^\d{1,3}(?:\,\d{3})*((?:,\d+)+)*?$/;
  let matches = number.match(regex);

  if (matches[1]) {
    number = number.replace(matches[1], matches[1].replace(/,/g, '.'))
  }
  return number;
}

console.log(commaToDot('4,4444'));
console.log(commaToDot('5,555'));
console.log(commaToDot('3,33'));
console.log(commaToDot('1,234,45,6789'));
console.log(commaToDot('1,234,45,678,9'));
console.log(commaToDot('5,5,5,5,5'));
```

This will match everything after the numbers stop being part of the `\d{1,3},\d{3}` pattern, and replace their commas with dots.

From what I gather, this is what you are looking for.

**Edit**

After leaving my comment above to check validity of "1,333.22,333", I've had to re-write the regex slightly:

```js
function commaToDot(number) {
  let regex = /(?!,\d{3},)(,\d{0,2})|(,\d{4,})/g,
    matches = number.match(regex);

  if (matches) {
    matches.forEach((match) => {
      number = number.replace(match, match.replace(/,/g, '.'));
    });
  }
  return number 
}

console.log(commaToDot('1,234,45,678,9'));
console.log(commaToDot('4,4444'));
console.log(commaToDot('5,555'));
console.log(commaToDot('3,33'));
console.log(commaToDot('1,234,45,6789'));
console.log(commaToDot('5,5,5,5,5'));
console.log(commaToDot('12,345,678,90'));
```

This should now do what you would like it to do.

Answer (score 0):

With `RegExp.test()` function and specific regex patterns:

```js
var commaToDot = function(str){
    if (/^-?\d+[,\d]+\d+$/.test(str) && /\d+,(\d{1,2}|\d{4,})\b/.test(str)){
        var parts = str.split(',');
        return parts.length > 2? parts[0] +','+ parts.slice(1).join('.') : parts.join('.');
    } else {
        return str;
    }
};

console.log(commaToDot('4,4444'));
console.log(commaToDot('5,555'));
console.log(commaToDot('3,33'));
console.log(commaToDot('1,234,45,6789'));
```

Comment: it converted the '1,234,45,6789' to 1.234.45.6789 
should have been 1,234.45.6789

Comment: 5,5,5 return 5,5.5 now. :') its not doable through regex i guess

Comment: @mugheesilyas, *or less than 3 digits* - that's your condition. So you have confused yourself and others

Comment: @KyleFairns, you indeed were confused. Otherwise, the OP's phrase *that is 4,444 is correct* is ambiguous according to your assumption

Comment: No, it simply means leave that comma alone, no change should occur to that particular one, as it is correctly formatted. The comma has exactly 3 digits behind it, which means `x == 3`.

Comment: @KyleFairns, I think the OP is confused and he didn't accept any answer ...

Comment: Because your answer converts `5,5,5` to `5,5.5` when it should be `5.5.5`. Your answer does not fit the requirements, as the amount of digits behind the comma is 1 in this example, which should turn it into a dot.

Comment: @KyleFairns, I don't think so, that's doubtful